# Does the Bottom AppBar show on swipe works by default in XAML/C# app?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-8

Do I need to explicitly do anything to make Bottom AppBar appear on swipe? Or is it a default behavior of AppBars to work on swipe?

I have tested and it works fine on Right Mouse click.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swiping up from the bottom should make the bottom AppBar appear.

In Windows 8 development you can start up your application in a simulator. This option is up where you choose build configuration and by default it says "Local Machine" (or did for me). Once you start up the simulator you can look on the right-hand side of the simulator window and there's a button to switch to swipe mode. You can use this to test.